# Why is English written and read left to right?

Tags: writing, reading

Why is English written and read from left-to-right as opposed to right-to-left, top-to-bottom, or (not even sure any language does this) bottom-to-top?

Comment: If it had been written in another direction, wouldn't you still have asked the question? :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Naturally, but in another direction. :-)

Comment: I can actually answer the second half of the question. English is read left-to-right because it is written left-to-right. I imagine it would be quite hard to write it in one direction, and read in the other. Hope that helps.

Comment: @RegDwight: LOL. But fact is stranger than humour: Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_system#Directionality) "Several scripts used in the Philippines and Indonesia, such as Hanunó'o, are traditionally written with lines moving away from the writer, from bottom to top, but are read horizontally left to right." Incredible! But it turns out [Hanunó'o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanun%C3%B3'o_script) is usually written on bamboo sticks and the writing is done bottom-to-top (this answers one of Chris's questions as well); presumably they rotate the bamboo stick before reading.

Comment: @RegDwight: I'm looking at my "written and read" as one entity. But, I understand your quibble. :-)

Comment: Does "all languages point to Jerusalem" help in any way for a remembering aid? There are many diverse "references" to this and such similar online.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Writing in English was derived from writing in Latin (it's mostly the same alphabet, after all), which in turn was derived from writing in Greek — which was written from left to right. So this is why all European writing systems go from left to right: because they're derived from Greek.

---

But why did the Greeks write from left to right? I'm not sure. They adopted their alphabet from Phoenician (or, if you wish, Proto-Canaanite), which was actually mostly written right to left (and sometimes [boustrophedonically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon): direction alternates every line, so that each line starts just below where the previous line ends). In fact, Greek *used* to write from right to left for a while, before they switched to left-to-right.

Another derivative from Proto-Canaanite was Aramaic, from which Hebrew, Arabic, Persian etc. are derived, and they're all still written right-to-left. It is also believed that Brahmi (the family of Indic scripts) was derived from Aramaic and was written right-to-left for a while, before switching to left-to-right.

Why did this switch happen, in Greek and Brahmi? According to a theory mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) without a citation (so it may just be an urban legend),

> Many languages that existed before the invention of ink were written right to left since this is the more natural for right handed people to hold a chisel in the left hand and the hammer in the right. After ink became the main method of writing, writing from left to right became preferable since it avoided smudging the ink.

Make of that what you will. It *is* known that Chinese, Japanese and Korean are written in vertical columns going from top to bottom and ordered right to left because it "facilitated writing with a brush in the right hand while continually unrolling the sheet of paper or scroll with the left". (The Chinese invented paper, after all.) So there may be merit to the explanation quoted above, that the medium influenced the writing direction.

Comment: That sounds rather convincing. Note that the Chinese did not invent paper, just a new, inexpensive way of making it.

Comment: As a right-handed person I must say smudging when writing in Hebrew is *really* annoying.

Comment: "boustrophedonically" -- I'll have to start using that word in my everyday speech. :)

Comment: @Cerberus: Depends on your definition of paper. I don't consider papyrus, parchment or vellum as being really paper, so the [history of paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_paper) begins with China IMO.

Comment: Hmm well I suppose that this is open to discussion. While I'd never call parchment or vellum paper, I do like to think of papyrus as paper. Which part of the process is it that you find essential? The use of small fibres? I heard that modern paper can be made of all sorts of plant materials. And some shops specialized in paper also sell modern papyrus, i.e. "paper" made by pressing unprocessed slices of reeds or leaves or other parts of plants together and letting them dry. I especially cannot get over judging the word that our word "paper" came from as non-paper... long live Antiquity!

Comment: @Cerberus: The definition of paper is really up to you, but a note on the words. It's part of the natural chauvinism/convenience of every civilization to seek words for foreign inventions from its own culture. E.g. many Indian languages have ancient-sounding Sanskrit names for concepts that are really inventions of the modern West. In particular, just as the word "paper" came from the familiar writing material "papyrus" (which word is Greek BTW, not the native Egyptian name), a word for paper in Indian languages comes from the word for leaf (palm leaves being traditional writing material)...

Comment: ... so, just as you are surprised that [papyrus] is considered as non-[paper], some may well be surprised (though admittedly with much weaker cause) that [palm leaves] are considered non-[modern word for paper] — even the word for paper comes from palm leaves!

Comment: Good point. I think my "definition" is rather more intuitive: papyrus looks and feels much like paper (I am comparing old papyrus with old paper): they are brittle and have a fibrous structure, as opposed to parchment, which is more leathery. I suppose I am just a traditionalist. In my country, we have an old word for refrigerator, "ice-chest", which was coined in the time when food was cooled by blocks of ice. Modern refrigerators do not use ice for that, and hence many people started calling them "cool-chests". I am among those who refuse to drop the old name, of whom there are still many.

Answer (score 14):

English writing, like almost all alphabetic scripts used today, ultimately derives from a [Phoenician alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenician_script) used around 3000 years ago. The direction of writing was variable early on - some texts are written in [boustrophedon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/boustrophedon), "as the ox ploughs", which means that alternate lines are written in opposite directions. 
At some point Greek script settled down to left-to-right, and all the European scripts which derive from it (Latin (i.e. English), Cyrillic, Georgian, Armenian) adopted this pattern. Most middle-eastern scripts (eg Hebrew, Arabic, Aramaic) settled down to right-to-left. Descendants further out (eg Indian and south-east Asian scripts, and also African scripts such as [Amharic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amharic_script)) are mostly left-to-right.

Nobody really knows why particular scripts settled in particular directions; but it has often been remarked that left-to-right is easier for right-handed scribes using pen and ink, because there is less chance of smudging what you have already written.

Comment: I've just recalled that many of the letters in Phoenician turned through 90 degrees at some point, and there is a theory that this happened when scribes changed how they held their tablets and came to write horizontally rather than vertically. I don't remember the details though.